# Place image at the bottom of the DIV

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

**DEMO:** [**https://jsfiddle.net/sbxbeqfy/**](https://jsfiddle.net/sbxbeqfy/)

I'm creating a layout which has text on the left and an image to the right. I have to place the image to the bottom of the div at all screens. I tried using `position: absolute` and also `vertical-align: bottom` but that didn't help. I tried various methods too but that didn't help. How should I proceed?

By default, the image is placed at the top of the div :(

```
<div class="App">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-7">
                    <h1>Welcome</h1>
                    <h2>This is the best and there's been no better measure.</h2>
                    <br />
                    <h2>Available on Play Store</h2>
                    <form>
                    <input type="number" class="mobile" />
                    </form>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5 mobile">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="NextApp">
        <div class="conainer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-7">
                  The image above is to touch the top of this div in any screen size
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.App {
  padding: 15px 0;
}
.mobile {
  bottom: 0px;
}
.NextApp {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you already tried http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media-alignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `display: flex` (parent) and `align-self: flex-end` (children). I've added a `media query` for the mobile view and a new class called `imageBottom`.

See this snippet:

```css
.App {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.NextApp {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.imageBottom {
  display: flex;
}

.mobile {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

@media (max-width: 755px) { 
  .imageBottom {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="App">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row imageBottom">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-7">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <h2>This is the best and there's been no better measure. This is the best and there's been no better measure.This is the best and there's been no better measure.This is the best and there's been no better measure.This is the best and there's been no better measure.This is the best and there's been no better measure.</h2>
        <br />
        <h2>Available on Play Store</h2>
        <form>
          <input type="number" class="mobile" />
        </form>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5 mobile">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="NextApp">
  <div class="conainer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-7">
        The image above is to touch the top of this div in any screen size
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex` on the parent row (added a new class, `.specialRow`), and `align-self: flex-end` on `.mobile` to put it at the bottom.

```css
.App {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.NextApp {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.specialRow {
  display: flex;
}

.mobile {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .specialRow {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="App">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row specialRow">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-7">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <h2>This is the best and there's been no better measure. This is the best and there's been no better measure.This is the best and there's been no better measure.This is the best and there's been no better measure.This is the best and there's been no better measure.This is the best and there's been no better measure.</h2>
        <br />
        <h2>Available on Play Store</h2>
        <form>
          <input type="number" class="mobile" />
        </form>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5 mobile">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/640x480" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="NextApp">
  <div class="conainer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-7">
        The image above is to touch the top of this div in any screen size
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```